# When will the Microsoft Bot Framework support Facebook Chat Extensions

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger

Facebook recently announced Chat Extensions which will allow group-based interaction with bots. More about how that works is listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/design/guides/chat-extensions

Has any announcement been made about when the Microsoft Bot Framework will support this feature of FB?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make a new issue asking for this enhancement [on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues)